# What's the correct Angular / Firebase way to edit one object at a time from a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have an Angular / Firebase application that lets the user select a part from a list of parts. Each part has multiple fields and I want the user to be able to edit the fields for the part they pick. Everything should be 3-way bound to Firebase and all updates synced automatically.

My Firebase data would look like this:

```
{
  "partList": {
    "part1": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3"
    },
    "part2": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3"
    },
    "part3": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

Listing the parts is done with this ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in partList">{{key}}</div>
```

However, I'm not sure how to add form fields for the 3 fields on each part and have them correctly bind to the proper part when the user clicks on one in the list.

I tried using $bindTo with a $scope variable to the correct Firebase child when a part was clicked, but calling $bindTo more than once on the same scope variable resulted in a weird state where multiple objects in Firebase seemed to be bound to each other and seemed not to work (e.g. the previous bind didn't stop when I did more binds).

I can copy the object to a different $scope variable and then model that object to my input fields, but I lose 3-way binding when I do that and have to update Firebase manually.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: "Everything should be 3-way bound to Firebase and all updates synced automatically." this is a convenience, and would be nice, not a requirement of your app. You can call $save() to apply changes and shouldn't be overly eager to try and use $bindTo to solve every problem.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS handles the binding with a simple directive.  For a form input, you would use "ng-model", and with a clickable link, you can use "ng-click".  I'm not familiar with Firebase, so I can't address your 3-way binding issue without seeing the rest of your code.

You could inject these values into the global scope, but it is better practice not to, especially if you are writing a large app.

Also, you may want to consider converting your data to an array of objects like I've done in my script.js below.  I'm not saying it's the only way, but it seems like it would be much simpler to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Here's my Index.Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="MainController as mc">
  <h3>Select Part</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="part in mc.partList">
    <a href ng-click="mc.selectPart(part)">{{part.id}} </a>
    <ul>

      <li >{{part.field1}}</li>
      <li>{{part.field2}}</li>
      <li>{{part.field3}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<form action="">
  <h3>Edit Part</h3>
  Selected Part = {{mc.selectedPart.id}}
  <br><br>
  Field 1:  <input type="text" ng-model="mc.selectedPart.field1">
  <br><br>
  Field 2:  <input type="text" ng-model="mc.selectedPart.field2">
  <br><br>
  Field 3:  <input type="text" ng-model="mc.selectedPart.field3">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit"> <!--TODO Wire up the submit button to bind data to a data access layer-->
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

And the Script.js

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('MainController', MainController);

 function MainController() {
    var me = this;

     me.partList = [{
      "id": "part1",
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3"
    }, {
      "id": "part2",
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3"
    }, {
      "id": "part3",
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3"
    }];

  me.selectPart=  function(part) {
      me.selectedPart = part;
  };  
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I initially implemented and works great with Angular's 2-way data binding, but when (in your example) me.partList is bound to a Firebase object 3-way data binding did not extend to "selectedPart" which was not what I expected.

I would use arrays but Firebase handles objects better so I am using objects in this case.

This application has gotten medium sized, so I'm thinking it would be worthwhile to go back to basics and try to make a minimum failing test case in Plunker. I'll post it here if/when I get it working (or failing).

Comment: I just looked over Firebase's docs a bit.  I don't have time to dive into coding with it, but it looks like they are recommending your type of data to be formatted as array.  "Synchronized arrays should be used for any list of objects that will be sorted, iterated, and which have unique IDs. The synchronized array assumes that items are added using $add(), and that they will therefore be keyed using Firebase push IDs."

"We create a synchronized array with the $firebaseArray service."

Comment: It also is apparent the 3-way binding could get "chatty" on the network with  frequent round-trips to the server to store and get data.  It's not as big a problem if you're only going to be running it locally or on an intranet, but I wouldn't recommend it for mobile apps or anything with limited bandwidth.  Good luck!!!

Comment: Yesterday I was able to create a repeatable failing case where Firebase synchronization will fail any time I have a 3-way bind on a variable that is edited in a text or textarea form control. Synchronization using the method you show above is working perfectly.

My temporary solution is to use Angular's bind to a $scope variable that isn't 3-way bound to Firebase and then use a $timeout to update Firebase whenever the field has been idle for 1 second.

I'm going to also create a minimum failing example in Plunker. I'll post it here when I have done that.

Thanks for the hep!